# How to generify a class' fields setters coming from different objects

Tags: java

I have the following classes structure:

```
class Foo{
  private String a;
  private String b;
  private String c;
  
  // getters, setters and stuff
}

class A{
  public Foo fill(FooA fooA){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setA(fooA.getA());
    foo.setB(fooA.getB());
    foo.setC(fooA.getC());
    return foo;
  }

  public Foo fill(FooB fooB){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setA(fooB.getX().getA());
    foo.setB(fooB.getX().getB());
    foo.setC(fooB.getC());
    return foo;
  }
}
```

Whats the best way to do this? As u can see, FooA and FooB are kind of DTO classes that have different fields which fill the Foo class fields.
However, fill(FooA fooa) and fill(FooB fooB) have really similar code.

Comment: In this case, Foo, FooA and FooB should implement an interface SomeInterface with getters for a,b and c. Then your fill method only receives SomeInterface.

Comment: you should have a look at [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), a lib especially made for mapping beans like you do. (It doesn't seem that you have any class inheritance involved in your question, right?)

Comment: Another option for automatic mapping would be [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)